# How to read input from the terminal as you manipulate the stdout buffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, io, user-input

My problem is an extension of the problem listed here: [Bash or Python, When print characters to terminal, how to CHANGE a character at a FIXED position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149978/bash-or-python-when-print-characters-to-terminal-how-to-change-a-character-at)

I would like to ask the user to annotate some information that I am going to display on the screen. I would then like to collect their response, erase what has been displayed and display the new information in place for them to annotate.

If you attempt to use input or the sys.stdin methods then a new line will be generated and the new display will appear after the fact.

Is there a way to manipulate the output buffer while I take inputs?

Comment: If you need complete control of the terminal like that, you're likely going to be stuck with either `curses` (built-in module for complete terminal control), or maybe `prompt_toolkit` (third party package for writing custom terminals; used by `ipython` and others). Trying to do what you asked for (undo a newline already on `stdout`) is as hard in Python [as it is in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4531000/364696) (though as [an answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531057/364696) notes, on some terminals, ANSI escape sequences could be used, it's just not portable).